# Ionic/Angular send SMS to multiple numbers from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I have a project that I want to send an SMS to a list of contacts that I have.
unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and everything I try just does not seem to work.

I want to iterate through all the numbers in the array and then send an SMS with the IONIC SMS Plugin to these numbers.

Here is the Component that stores that contacts

```
constructor(private contacts: Contacts, private storage: Storage) {
    this.getContact();
  }
  key = 'contacts';
  mContacts = [
   {
    id: [0],
    name: '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: [1],
    name : [''],
    number: ['']
   },
   {
    id: [2],
    name : [''],
    number: ['']
   },
   {
    id: [3],
    name : [''],
    number: ['']
   },
   {
    id: [4],
    name : [''],
    number: ['']
   }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}

  pickContact(contactId) {
    this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
      this.mContacts[contactId].name = contact.name.givenName;
      this.mContacts[contactId].number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
      this.saveContacts();
    });
  }
  saveContacts() {
    this.storage.set(this.key, JSON.stringify(this.mContacts));
  }
  getContact() {
    this.storage.get(this.key).then((val) => {
      console.log('Contact Name: ', val);
      if (val != null && val !== undefined) {
        this.mContacts = JSON.parse(val);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and here is the function that sends the SMS. it starts with getContacts() method, as the Contacts are originally stored with the IONIC storage Plugin

## EDIT

I want to retrieve the contents of the the array list from the Contacts Component, however when I call the function sendSMS() it returns a null for the number

```
sendSMS()
{
  this.contactComponent.getContact();
  let number = this.contactComponent.mContacts[0][2];

  let message = "Hello World";
  console.log("number=" + number + ", message= " + message);

  //CONFIGURATION
  var options = {
      replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
      android: {
          intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
          //intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
      }
  };



  this.sms.send(number, message, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone.

I decided to do this instead to make things simplier.

```
 this.checkSMSPermission();
  this.contactComponent.getContact();
  const numberOne = this.contactComponent.mContacts[0].number;
  const numberTwo = this.contactComponent.mContacts[1].number;
  const numbeThree = this.contactComponent.mContacts[2].number;
  const numberFour = this.contactComponent.mContacts[3].number;
  const numberFive = this.contactComponent.mContacts[4].number;
  console.log(numberOne);

  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  const message = this.messageComponent.dangerMessage + ' my location is: lat: ' + this.latitude.toString() + 'lng: ' + this.longitude.toString();
  console.log('number=' + numberOne + ', message= ' + message);

  // CONFIGURATION
  const options = {
      replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
      android: {
          intent: ''  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
          // intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
      }
  };
  this.sms.send(numberOne,numberTwo ,numberThree,numberFour,numberFive, message, options).then(() => {
    this.presentAlert('Success', 'message has been sent');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.presentAlert('Error', 'Failed: ' + error);
  });
}
```